# При установке параметра reply_markup, ответ не приходит. Телеграм бот

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Телеграм бот на laravel. Все работает хорошо, но кода я устанавливаю дополнительный параметр reply_markup, сообщения не приходят и в логах ошибки нету.

```
 $buttons = [
        'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [
                [
                    'text' => 'My Button Text',
                    'callback_data' => ''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

 $telegram->sendGanres($chat_id,$content,json_encode($buttons));

public function sendGanres($chat_id,$content,$buttons)
    {
       return Http::post(self::TM_URL.$this->tm_api_key.'/sendMessage',[

           'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
           'text' => $content,
           'reply_markup' => $buttons

        ]);
    }
```

> если закомментировать reply_markup, то работает.

Comment: Потому что `callback_data` пуста и соответственно ничего не пришлет

Comment: Так не честно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял вам нужно сделать обработку нажатия на `InlineButton`

Вот пример как это сделать на C#:

Создаем саму клавиатуру:

```
 InlineKeyboardMarkup submenu_propertShower = new(new[] {
       new[]
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("♻️ В начало меню ♻️", callbackData: "key_mainMenu")
        } });
```

Делаем обработчик:

```
    switch (context.Update?.CallbackQuery?.Data)
                {
                    case "key_mainMenu":
                        await context.Client.SendTextMessageAsync(
                            chatId: context.ChatId,
                            text: "Текст",
                            replyMarkup: key.mainMenu,
                            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        break;
               }
```

Comment: Ваш первый комментарий помог мне, спасибо)